# Generate N-channel audio file with tone in only one channel?

Tags: audio, sox

How can I use [sox](http://sox.sourceforge.net/) to generate an N-channel audio file with silence in all but one channels? For instance, I'd like to create an 8-channel audio file with a tone in channel 3, and silence in all the others.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `remix` command. This takes an M-channel input, and generates an N-channel output, where for each output channel you specify the input source channel(s).

For example:

```
sox -n output.aif synth 1 sine 300 remix 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
```

does the following:

- `-n`: no input file
- `output.aif`: the output file where the results will be written
- `synth 1 sine 300`: generate a 1-second 1-channel sine wave at 300Hz
- `remix 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0`: convert this to an 8-channel file, where output channel 3 comes input channel 1 (the generated sine), and the others come from channel 0 (which is silence)

`remix` can specify more complex source functions for each output channel. Some examples of these specs:

- `2`: copy input channel 2 to output channel
- `0`: copy silence to output channel
- `2,3`: mix input channels 2 and 3 to output channel
- `1-4`: mix input channels 1 through 4 to output channel
- `-`: mix all input channels to output channel
- `1,2v0.5`: mix input channels 1 and 2, with 2 at half the volume of channel 1

(When mixing multiple input channels to an output channel, there are various rules for the mixed signal levels; consult [the documentation](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sox).)